# How can I join all data of two raster datasets in ArcMap 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, merge

I have two raster datasets in ArcMap10.2. One is displaying rails and one that is displaying a 100m Buffer to both sides of it. My cellsize is 100x100m.
What I want is to combine the rails AND the Buffer around it in one raster. All tools that I used only display the overlapping rasters in the new raster dataset, but I want to have ALL data in the new raster.

I tried Multiply and Plus in the raster calculator. I tried 'Mosaic To New Raster'. I tried merge... Actually I tried all possible union, combine, merge, join etc functions that I know about in ArcGIS. Either they just don´t work or I don´t get the result that I want.

Does anyone know how I can join the two rasters to have all data in the new layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked with the 'Mosaic To New Raster' tool. I used MAXIMUM as Mosaic Operator. I have no idea why it works now, suddenly, and did not work when I tried it earlier. But now I have my layer and that´s important ^^.

Thanks for all the answers and helping comments!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single raster output, probably map algebra with something like :

```
Con(IsNull("rail"), "buffer", "rail") 

Con("rail" > 0, "rail", "buffer")
```

will work (with rail and buffer the names of your layers. In the firest case, the background is No Data, and in the second case it is 0.

Otherwise, you might want to use "composite band" to create a 2 band raster that will contain all the values.

Comment: If I try the Con function in the Raster Calculator from Map Algebra I get a new layer which is empty. I´m wondering if my settings are wrong in some way ... The extension is on Spatial Analyst and I´m using the coordiante system WGS_1984_PDC_Mercator

Comment: With the 'Composite Band' tool I actually get a result, but this is only displaying one value which is the Buffer. There is no data displaying the rails.

Comment: I assume that your layers overlap in the same CRS. I have edited my answer if your background is "NoData"

Comment: I stil get the same result. A new empty layer which  has a Stretched Symbology with values from -2147483648 to 2147483647

Comment: are your input single band rasters ?

Comment: Yes, both have 1 Band

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[Conditional Toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Conditional_tools/009z00000004000000/)** in Spatial Analyst.  Without knowing the type of values in your rasters, it's difficult to say which one will be best for you.  But I think the **[Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/)** tool will probably do what you want.

Comment: If I run the Con Tool I get Error 010423 : <value> does not have valid statistics as required by the operation.

Comment: With the Pick Tool I also get a new empty layer which has a Stretched Symbology with values from -2147483648 to 2147483647

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Combine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Combining_multiple_rasters/009z00000083000000/) tool *which takes multiple input rasters and assigns a new value for each unique combination of input values in the output raster*

Comment: You may need to assign a "value" to your no data cells for the combine tool to work properly.